# iOS: change notification settings from 'Never Requested' to 'Denied' programmatically

Tags: ios, push-notification, notifications, apple-push-notifications

On iOS if you never asked user for notification permissions then this option will not appear in device settings for your application.

I wonder is there a way make this option appear in the settings in 'Denied' state without prompting a notificatoin permissions request so user can enable this option later by himself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that is not permitted. If it were possible to change authorizationStatus programmatically, or set it to some default state, then you would able to set it to 'authorized' state too, without asking user about it.